# kubetnetes port forward udp

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

My service exposes UDP port 6831, and other ports. Here is the service description:

```
    kubectl describe service jaeger-all-in-one                                                                                                                    1:51 
Name:           jaeger-all-in-one
Namespace:      myproject
Labels:         jaeger-infra=all-in-one
Annotations:        <none>
Selector:       name=jaeger-all-in-one
Type:           ClusterIP
IP:         172.30.213.142
Port:           query-http  80/TCP
Endpoints:      172.17.0.3:16686
Port:           agent-zipkin-thrift 5775/UDP
Endpoints:      172.17.0.3:5775
Port:           agent-compact   6831/UDP
Endpoints:      172.17.0.3:6831
Port:           agent-binary    6832/UDP
Endpoints:      172.17.0.3:6832
Session Affinity:   None
Events:         <none>
```

Forward port:

```
kubectl port-forward jaeger-all-in-one-1-cc8wd  12388:6831
```

However it forwards only TCP ports, I would like to send data to the UDP port.

Comment: kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.2", GitCommit:"477efc3cbe6a7effca06bd1452fa356e2201e1ee", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-04-19T20:33:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2+43a9be4", GitCommit:"43a9be4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-04-21T15:37:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: It does not work for 1.6.4 either.

Comment: no this is not yet supported (as now v1.12) https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47862

Comment: I'm from 2022 and K8s is at 1.23 -- still not supported, the GitHub ticket is still open